# Finding rotation of an object that has contours

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I have this image of rectangular objects:

[image: Image of Rectangular objects]

I want to be able to find the angle of rotation of each object (the circle facing up being 180 degrees).

My Idea: I will first locate each part and draw a contour around each rectangular object, then I will identify each circle within that object and draw a contour. I will draw a straight line that will act as a constant in the center of the image then I will draw a straight line on each part with the 'North' side of the line going towards the small circle. Then using the constant and that line find the angle between the two lines.

So how would I go about doing this? I'm open to other ideas, but this is the simplest I could come up with and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

This is what I have. I need to index each contour and add numbers to identify each one once its drawn. `AreaMin` & `AreaMax` are trackbars for area.

```
if areaMin < area < areaMax:
    cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 7)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * peri, True)
    x , y , w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    cv2.rectangle(imgContour, (x , y ), (x + w , y + h ), (255, 0, 0), 5)
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it like you described? That sounded like you had a good plan.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add lines to an identified contour.

Comment: Can you show an example of how an identified contour is represented in your program?

Comment: This is when they are drawn then I have a BoundingRect and text for area and points.Sorry not sure why my code won't stay formatted.

Comment: Use cv.minAreaRect() to get the rotated bounding box. From that you can get the angle. Or fit ellipse to the contour and get the angle from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could calculate the length of two sides of the rectangle and their ratio, and then use math.atan() method to get the angle